# Facebook Api Graph Pull data from a timeframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to this stuff, I am trying to use Facebook api Graph to get the data for the last 30 days and link it to Klipfolio.

I am able to pull all the data but no matter what i try I can not seam to get FB to only return all of the data not just last 30 days or 7days.

am I able to a time frame parameters?

Any help would be appreciated, this is what I have to pull all the data,

/adaccounts?fields=amount_spent

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't use facebook adds so i can't exactly test with data . but facebook graph api supports time based pagination of the data  . read the time based pagination section at the graph api [v2.2 docs page.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#reading) .

it provides with **until** and **since** parameters.

> A time-paginated edge supports the following parameters:
>
> - **until** : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the
>     end of the range of time-based data.
> - **since** : A Unix timestamp or
>     strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of
>     time-based data.

i checked it with end points like

```
me/feed?until=10/11/2011
```

and it works as expected . so test the parameter for your required data .

Comment: Thanks.  this works when  I can call data for one page PAGENAME/insights/page_fan_adds?since={date.last30Days}&until={date.today} but if i try to do it for ad accounts the date parameters do not work, it just gives total values.

Comment: @JohnMackin then i guess they haven't implemented the filter parameters for the node /adaccounts node yet i guess :) . sorry